# OctoberCms Blog plugin categories into 'activeMenuItem' function?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

Show "slug" category in Post:

```
{{ post.categories[0].slug }}
```

But, how to add this "slug" to 'activeMenuItem'?

```
function onInit()
{
 $this['activeMenuItem'] = ???;
}
```

Thanks!

**UPD**, for use here:

```
{% for item in items %}
<a href="{{ item.url }}">
<span class="{{ item.isActive or item.isChildActive ? ' active' : '' }}">{{ item.title }}</span>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEnd() {
    $this['activeMenuItem'] = $this->post->categories[0]->slug;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign variables in twig as well

```
{% set activeMenuItem = post.categories[0].slug %}
```

> Now use this variable into your menu partial

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: hmm, 
`{% set activeMenuItem = post.categories[0].slug %}
{{ activeMenuItem }}` - shows category,  but doesn't work here : 
`{% for item in items %} <a href="{{ item.url }}"><span class="{{ item.isActive or item.isChildActive ? ' active' : '' }}">{{ item.title }}</span></a>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: means what you trying to achieve can you share more details about it so we can help you better